# use RewriteMap in htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewritemap

How can i use RewriteMap directive in htaccess file?
When i put it there i get "RewriteMap not allowed here" error.

I know this error will disappear when put it in httpd.conf or virtualhost configuration file.
But i want to know is it possible to put it in htaccess or not?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap):

> Context:    server config, virtual host

so the answer is "no", I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know it cannot be used in htaccess.

Maybe you could check this out as an alternative: http://savride.wordpress.com/2008/09/09/rewritemap-directive-in-htaccess-file-problem/