# Rewrite map without access to htdocs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache-config, rewritemap

I'm on a virtual server so I don't have access to Apache's htdocs; all I have is .htaccess. Is it still possible to do a rewrite map? What kind of workarounds are there?

Comment: Try it yourself, and if it doesn't work, THAT is when you're ready to come ask others for help.

Comment: What kind of rewrite map do you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the documentation you will see that, in the doc field named 'Context', the RewriteMap directive may be used in the server config or in the virtual host config. It is not permitted in directory or .htaccess - to be clear, the answer is No, it is not still possible to do a rewrite map if all you have access to is .htaccess.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap

The only 'workaround' would be to define a RewriteCond and RewriteRule for every mapping that you need. These can be defined in .htaccess.

This question was already answered in

[use RewriteMap in htaccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975614/use-rewritemap-in-htaccess-file)